# load bloomberg page from c#

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

I have an old excel workbook that I am trying to replace with a c# application. The only bit of functionality that I have not been able to replicate is the code below.

So the code below takes a bloomberg ticker (i.e. "VOD LN") and then with DDEInitiate it loads the bloomberg page.

I have read that C# doesn't support DDE or even if it does it is best avoided. In which case how can I do this via C#?

```
Public Sub LoadBbergPage(string ticker)

' loads bberg page
Dim strExe As String
Dim channelGP As Long

channelGP = DDEInitiate("Winblp", "BBK")
strExe = "<blp-2><home>" & Strings.Trim(ticker) & "<EQUITY><GO>"
DDEExecute channelGP, strExe
DDETerminate channelGP

End Sub
```

Comment: [GlobalClass.DDEInitiate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.globalclass.ddeinitiate.aspx)

Comment: @WaiHaLee does that class load without Excel being installed? I assume the OP wants to get rid of the dependency on Excel.

Comment: @rene - it definitely does require Excel to be installed. I hadn't read the question as an attempt to get rid of the dependence on Excel, but on second reading, perhaps you are right.

Comment: You might give [NDDE](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ndde+%5Bc%23%5D) a try.

Comment: Maybe even better: use the native C# API: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make it easier for your users to launch data into the terminal, you can use 'B-links'. Access it like any other web link. Below is an example for "IBM US Equity" - replace spaces with `%20`

`https://blinks.bloomberg.com/securities/[ticker]/[function]`
https://blinks.bloomberg.com/securities/IBM%20US%20Equity/DES

It will ask the user the first time to allow / remember settings and then should launch to terminal. If there are issues, you can go to https://blinks.bloomberg.com/help. Documentation is available on terminal via `DOCS BLINKS<GO>` (tons more special syntax)

But if you're trying to do some kind of screen scraping etc via DDE, don't bother; just use the Reference Data API instead: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/